# Show that $7(3(2)^k + 2(5)^k) - 10(3(2)^{k-1} + 2(5)^{k-1}) = 3(2)^{k+1} + 2(5)^{k+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$7(3(2)^k + 2(5)^k) - 10(3(2)^{k-1} + 2(5)^{k-1}) = 3(2)^{k+1} + 2(5)^{k+1}$

The problem is part of a proof. If you could also talk me through your thought process for solving this problem, I would greatly appreciate it. I've played around with several things like trying to get everything in terms of $a^{k+1}$ but I'm having no luck. Thanks!

Comment: your last bracket is ) instead of }

Comment: Looks like you may need to fix your curly brackets.  That should take care of the latex, but I think you may be missing some parentheses as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the missing right parenthesis goes at the end:

$$7(3(2)^k + 2(5)^k) - 10(3(2)^{k-1} + 2(5)^{k-1}) =\\21\cdot 2^k+14\cdot 5^k-30\cdot 2^{k-1} -20\cdot 5^{k-1}=\\ 21\cdot 2^k +14\cdot 5^k-15\cdot 2^k-4\cdot 5^k=\\ 6\cdot 2^k+10\cdot 5^k=\\3(2)^{k+1} + 2(5)^{k+1}$$

Comment: Even though the original post doesn't seem to have gained favor in the eyes of many (it's got 0 votes as of today), I think this solution validates this question's existence enough to warrant a vote.  I have been struggling with exponents like (k-1) but seeing it worked out helped quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ Note that $\rm\,\color{#C00}{2}^k,\, \color{#0A0}5^k\:$ are solutions of the *linear* recurrence $\rm\:f(k\!+\!1) - 7 \ f(k) + 10\ f(k\!-\!1) = 0\:$ hence so too are all linear combinations $\rm\:c\, 2^k + d\, 5^k,\:$ for $\rm\:c,d\:$ constants (independent of $\rm\:k$).

If you know a little about recurrences you can make it even easier by noting that the characteristic polynomial is $\rm\ x^2-7x +10 = (x-\color{#C00}2)(x-\color{#0A0}5).$